# PHP POST request counter

Tags: php, cookies, counter

Is there a way to increment a variable each time someone makes a POST request. I don't mean 'page visits' or 'form submit' which refreshes the page.

I know I could use `PHP SESSION` for that. My page however does not refresh on POST request but rather makes a call to a PHP script which returns (adds) data to the page. How can I count each POST request for each user? Do I have to resort to cookies? And if cookies are the best/only approach, what is the best method available in PHP?

Comment: You could have a MySQL record for storing the post request, if you wanted to go that far. That way, it's not reliant on the client saving the data.

Comment: @Nerixel Yes I tried that and I experienced that database approach is to slow for what Im doing. Because an extra call has to be made to the database which slows down my script in a massive way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're free to use a session or an own cookie implementation, but in the end, both variants rely on a cookie sent by the client. There is no (sufficient) way to achieve this without a user token, because many users share the same IP address these days.

The most efficient way would be to use standard php sessions, because the user might reset the session to reset his POST counter, but he wouldn't be able to change the counter at his desire:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['postCounter']))
{
    $_SESSION['postCounter'] = 0;
}

if(count($_POST) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['postCounter']++;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I see what you are getting at but it doesnt work for me, Im still working on it though.